# How to add prefix to each paragraph of a certain style in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

Is there a way to add the same word (say 'Task') before each paragraphs of a certain style? Or before a group of paragraphs of the same style?

Answer (score 2):

In Microsoft Word 2013 you would do the following:

1. Define a new multi-level list
2. Set number style for this level to none
3. Enter format as the text you want prefixed to the line (e.g. "Task - ")
4. Set the font style for the prefix as desired (e.g. Bold Italic, Calibri 10)

I would also recommend creating a new style based on the line with the prefix, so that you can easily prefix lines just selecting your new style.

[Rabarberski is correct in saying](https://superuser.com/questions/155023/how-to-add-prefix-to-each-paragraph-of-a-certain-style-in-ms-word/222354#222354) normal numbered lists do not allow non-numeric prefixes, so you must use the multi-level list.

Answer (score 1):

If, by accident, you also want a counter in that text (say 'Task 1'), you could do it by defining a new number format with the appropriate text, and applying that number format to your style.

Unfortunately, it seems not possible to create new numbering formats without numbers in it (at least not in Office 2007, I *think* it was possible in previous versions). Otherwise, this would be quit a convenient workaround.

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately, it seems not possible to create new numbering formats
>   without numbers in it (at least not in Windows 2007, I think it was
>   possible in previous versions). Otherwise, this would be quit a
>   convenient workaround.

Actually this workaround can work in Microsoft Word 2007 and later versions but you need to use a *multi-level list* instead of just a regular numbered list as this type of list does not carry the number restriction that the regular list does. Create a new multilevel list and then select "Number style for this level" to none, enter the prefix into the formatting box and then select the name of your style under the "Link to style" drop down box.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to search/replace formatting with Edit/Replace. but i did not find a way how to insert something in front of the text at the same time. so i think you have to do it in more manual way.

1) record a simple macro with Edit/Find .. insert your style in the formatting .. 
2) push Home button to get to the front of the line
3) type your text
4) push Down arrow to move away from the paragraph
5) end macro recording. attach macro to some key.
6) keep pressing the key until EOF.
7) profit???